# SQL calculating running

Tags: sql, ms-access

I run an SQL query in my Access db to accumulate the distance I ran after each record.

I use the following code to calculate the running total:

```
SELECT a.run, a.year, a.date, a.distance, round((SELECT SUM(b.distance)
                       FROM vwAllCast b
                       WHERE b.run <= a.run),1) AS AccDistance
FROM vwAllCast AS a
ORDER BY a.run DESC;
```

This code returns all the records summing all distances in AccDistance. Now, I'd like to start the accumulation anew for each year. Has anyone got an idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: just add where clause to filter recrods

Comment: Or group by year to get all years in the same query result

Answer (score 0):

Like Piyush said, i think something like this should works:

```
SELECT a.run, a.year, a.date, a.distance, round((SELECT SUM(b.distance)
                       FROM vwAllCast b
                       WHERE b.run <= a.run and a.year = b.year),1) AS AccDistance
FROM vwAllCast AS a
ORDER BY a.run DESC;
```

Comment: thanks both FuzzyTree and Aramillo, buth queries work beautifully. The self join and group is a fair bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

A self join + group by might be faster than a correlated subquery

```
SELECT a.run, a.year, a.date, a.distance, SUM(b.distance)
FROM vwAllCast AS a
JOIN vwAllCast b on b.run <= a.run AND b.year = a.year
GROUP BY a.run, a.year, a.date, a.distance
ORDER BY a.run DESC
```